# Only one Boolean allowed

Tags: pandas, numpy

Can anyone help me how should I get output with only one Boolean value

I used df.isnull() to check Missing values and Output should contain only one Boolean value

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your data this should tell you if a column has even a single null value in it

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Column_1' : [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'Column_2' : [np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Column_2'].isnull().any()
```